# is it possible to put comments in a directory about a dir or file?

Tags: linux, command-line

is it possible to put comments in a directory about a dir or file *locally on my own machine*, appearing in my terminal. I don't have any kind of GUI, so this would be helpful.

Maybe something like, when I do `ls -l` I will see:

```
file.txt #this is that file I made on tuesday
files    #this is the directory I made with all those other files
```

If so, what is the tool to do it?

Is it available for Arch Linux?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, there is a tool for that. It is called GIT or SVN.

Comment: isn't that for pushing code to some kind of remote location or working on projects with others? I'm talking about locally on my own machine

Comment: yes it is usually used for code, but you may commit any file you want  and you can write comments on everything you commited. This way you don't only get informations on when you create something, you also keep informations about changes. Versioning systems are pretty powerful in that regard. and since there ain't other ways i could think of you should take a look into it.

Comment: i will consider that but, do you know what i really mean? i want the comments to just be locally on my terminal, wouldn't that be convenient?

Comment: you may write a shellscript which invokes on ls and reads the last comment from git per file...

Comment: To start tracking a directory tree, use `git init`. Then `git add <file>` and `git commit -m "Comment"`